# Lost on which book / guides to progress in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get into c++ but I'm struggling to find good learn material. Currenlty I'm using this free tutorial https://www.learncpp.com but I want to know what books I can buy to go from here. They should be new and help me get the necessary knowledge to understand new features from c11, c14 and c17. Can anyone point me into a direction? Thanks in advance !

(I have sufficient knowledge in other languages and the basics of cpp)

Comment: Unfortunately asking for recommendations is off-topic here as there's usually no singular correct answer, only a multitude of options.

Comment: Why is it offtopic? I'm not expecting a singular answer but hints what good new material regarding that was released. Other questions didn't answer as they mostly listed "best" books but I'm more interested in new ones.

Comment: The format here is for a specific technical question that has a specific technical answer. Recommendation-type questions lead to a lot of debate, so they're off-topic. Finding the book that's right for you is a matter of personal preference, not technical merit.

Comment: @nimnim questions like this can set off flame wars over who wrote the best book, what IDE is best, tabs or spaces, indentation style, Grover or Elmo... Take the duplicate link and run with it. Those are the generally agreed-upon best of breed books.

Comment: Most of the Internet is a festering pile of garbage, so you're smart to get a few books. A few good sites (IMO) for after you have a good grip on the language and basic concepts: [ISOCPP's FAQ page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq) and [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). [Herb Sutter's page](https://herbsutter.com/) often has some really neat stuff, advanced and basic.

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks for clarifying. Thanks for the links!